# Varnish+nginx+ hitch +lets encrypt configuration

Tags: ssl, encryption, nginx, varnish

I am a newbie to nginx. I installed Nginx +varnish+hitch+lets encrypt in linode ubuntu 16.04 server for testing.
I tried following instructions given in varnish blog and able to connect https://.

https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/five-steps-to-secure-varnish-with-hitch-and-lets-encrypt

The problem is , I don't know how to configure Nginx SSL. HTTPS and HTTP both are working fine. But not redirecting to default https.

i tried all nginx settings given in this link. But its not working https://vincent.composieux.fr/article/install-configure-and-automatically-renew-let-s-encrypt-ssl-certificate.

Let me know how to configure.

following is the Nginx file.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    # SSL configuration
    #
    # listen 443 ssl default_server;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
    #
    # Note: You should disable gzip for SSL traffic.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/773332
    #
    # Read up on ssl_ciphers to ensure a secure configuration.
    # See: https://bugs.debian.org/765782
    #
    # Self signed certs generated by the ssl-cert package
    # Don't use them in a production server!
    #
    # include snippets/snakeoil.conf;

    root /var/www/example.com/html/wordpress;
    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name  example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
     location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
     #fastcgi_index index.php;
      # include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
 deny all;
}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #       include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #
    #       # With php7.0-cgi alone:
    #       fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #       # With php7.0-fpm:
    #       fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #       deny all;
    #}
    }


    # Virtual Host configuration for example.com
    #
    # You can move that to a different file under sites-available/ and      symlink that
    # to sites-enabled/ to enable it.
    #
    #server {
    #       listen 80;
    #       listen [::]:80;
    #
    #       server_name example.com;
    #
    #       root /var/www/example.com;
    #       index index.html;
    #
    #       location / {
      {
    #               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    #       }
    #}
```

Comment: Possible answer http://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom

Comment: port number 443 is aleady used by hitch. which port given in nginx conf files?

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use HAProxy its very simple to setup,I now have

:443 HAPROXY(SSL)  :8080 VARNISH -> :9080 JBoss application

here is my haproxy config:

```
global
debug
log         127.0.0.1 local0
chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
maxconn     40
user        haproxy
group       haproxy
daemon
stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats
ssl-default-bind-ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:RC4-SHA:!kEDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL
ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
mode                    http
log                     global
option                  httplog
option                  dontlognull
retries                 3
timeout http-request    1m
timeout queue           1m
timeout connect         30s
timeout client          2m
timeout server          1m
timeout http-keep-alive 30s
timeout check           30s

listen stats
bind *:1936
stats enable
stats uri /
stats hide-version
stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
stats auth haproxy:PASS

frontend  main
bind 0.0.0.0:80
bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/<HOSTNAME>.pem
http-request set-header Host <HOSTNAME>
redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
acl is_root path -i /
acl is_domain hdr(host) -i <HOSTNAME>
redirect code 301 location https://<HOSTNAME>/<APP> if is_domain is_root
default_backend             app

backend app
mode http
balance     roundrobin
option forwardfor
acl h_xff_exists req.hdr(X-Forwarded-For) -m found
http-request replace-header X-Forwarded-For (.*) %[src],\1 if h_xff_exists
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
 default-server inter 10s fall 2 rise 1
 server var 127.0.0.1:8080 check
```